I am an imaginary variance
I was given autocorrelation function of an ergodic stochastic process. The autocorrelation function would be:
$$R_{x} \left ( \tau  \right )=\frac{\tau ^{2}}{2+9\tau ^{2}}$$
Here $E(X^2)$ is zero as $R_x(0) = 0$ and $E(x)$ is coming $0.33$ that would make variance imaginary. Is there anything wrong in my approach?

So, we seem to have a power $R_X(0)$ equal to zero, and a mean $\mu_X=\sqrt{\lim_{\tau\to\infty}R_X(\tau)}=1/3$, resulting in a variance
$$\sigma^2_X=R_X(0)-\mu_X^2=-\frac19\tag{1}$$
That would mean the end of our universe as we know it.
Luckily, there's a flaw here. The function some joker sold you as an autocorrelation function cannot be an autocorrelation function. A valid autocorrelation function must satisfy
$$|R_X(\tau)|\le R_X(0)\tag{2}$$
and yours doesn't. Universe saved.

the community thanks you collectively for saving the universe, especially on a Sunday morning :-)

Our Universe tolerates the existence of exotic probabilities such as negative probability or complex measure. Fortunately, we have collectively been able to avoid their use.
